# Vimeo API - Loading videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I know my way around jQuery and JavaScript a little bit but as for optimising, I'm a bit weak but willing to learn new stuff.

I'm currently loading videos onto our site from Vimeo when a user clicks the appropriate image area.  This is working fine, but I feel it's not an entirely performant way to go about doing it.

Does anyone see any issues with the code I've written below which could be done better?

```
var videoData = [
{
    'player_id':'video1',
    'videoURL':'<?php the_field('two_vimeo_video_url'); ?>',
    'width':'1000',
},
{
    'player_id':'video2',
    'videoURL':'<?php the_field('six_vimeo_video_url'); ?>',
    'width':'1000',
}];

function loadVideo(target, videoid) {
    $.getJSON('http://www.vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=' + encodeURIComponent(videoData[videoid]['videoURL']) + '&api=1&player_id='+ videoData[videoid]['player_id'] +'&width='+videoData[videoid]['width']+'&byline=0&color=ffffff&title=0'+'&callback=?', function(data){

        $(target).find('.video-container').html(data.html); // puts an iframe embed from vimeo's json

        $(target).closest('iframe').load(function(){

            $f(player).addEvent('ready', function(id){
                var vimeoVideo = $f(videoid);
            });
        });
    });
}

$(function(){
    // Create array to store values
    var vimeoArray = [];
    var videoContainer = $('.video-container');

    // loop through st
    $(videoContainer).each(function(index, value) {

        // get the image with the data attr on each loop
        var dataAttr = $(this).attr('data-video');

        // if dataAttr is not false
        if ( dataAttr !== undefined) {

            // push data attribute value into array
            vimeoArray.push(dataAttr);

            // Store last element of array on iteration
            var videoid = vimeoArray[vimeoArray.length-1];

            // attach click handler to the parent of the scoped element
            $(this).parent().click(function(){

                // load the video
                loadVideo(this, videoid);
                $(this).unbind('click');
                $(this).find('.b-studio__image').hide();

            });
        }
    });
});
```

I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RustyCollins/nx5gz5a6/1/) as well with all the code and some dummy data. Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: Is this a .js file or a .php file, I ask because I see `<?php the_field('two_vimeo_video_url'); ?>` in there

Comment: It's a php file but I re-created the the data in the jsfiddle to match output.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small point, but in general, its best not to create anonymous functions.
So for example:

```
$(function(){
    // Create array to store values
    var vimeoArray = [];
    var videoContainer = $('.video-container');

    // etc...
```

... should be contained inside a named function, and then called. 
See [Beware anonymous functions](http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/beware-anonymous-functions/).

Comment: Ah good point, that's a good link as well, I'd never seen it before thanks Hywel! (i'd upvote if I had rep dude!)

Comment: What the... The "Better" approach in that link is still using an anonymous function! I submitted a pull request to fix that ;)